# Embedding JavaScript objects in a page's URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to store a JavaScript object in the URL of a web page (as a JSON string), but the URL contains some characters that will not work with HTML links.

On this page, a JavaScript object is loaded from the page's URL:

`http://jsfiddle.net/tsUpC/1/show/#["Hello","World!"]`

and on this page, I'm trying to create a link to the same page that is shown above, but the URL contains characters that are not allowed in hyperlinks:

http://jsfiddle.net/M6dRb/

```
<a href = "http://jsfiddle.net/tsUpC/1/show/#["Hello","World!"]">This link doesn't work because the URL contains characters that are not allowed in HTML links.</a>
```

Is it possible to embed JavaScript objects into URLs without using characters that are not compatible with hyperlinks?

Comment: I'm trying to create a link to this page, but it contains characters that don't seem to work with hyperlinks. http://jsfiddle.net/tsUpC/1/show/#["Hello","World!"]

Comment: Wow, the link actually worked when I copied and pasted it into the comment above. I wonder how it was converted into a working hyperlink.

Comment: It worked because Stack Overflow properly escaped the quotes as `&quot;` in the HTML.

Comment: I found a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316452/how-to-pass-javascript-object-through-url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put a JSON string in an URL by URL-encoding it before putting it in the URL:

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object))
```

In [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/tsUpC/1/show/#%5B%22Hello%22%2C%22World!%22%5), that would be:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/tsUpC/1/show/#%5B%22Hello%22%2C%22World!%22%5D
```

As you might guess, the opposite of [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Answer (score -1):

You need to encode and decode with JSON

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
link.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // this could also be done with location.hash = JSON.stringify(...);
    var param = JSON.stringify(['your', 'array']),
        href = '#'+this.getAttribute('href');
    href += param;
    location.href = href;
}, false);


// make string an object/array again
var obj = JSON.parse(window.location.hash.substr(1));
```

Comment: I've already figured out that part. Now, I'll need to find a way to generate a link to a URL with special characters, like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/tsUpC/1/show/#["Hello","World!"]

Comment: You will probably need to use javascript to generate or alter the link by adding an onlclick.

Comment: It would be better if I could find a way to automatically encode and decode JSON strings to "URL-friendly" strings. There must be some way to do this.

Comment: You can do it with most, if not all, server-side languages